# Conditional Formatting Help

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I must be having an off day as I'm usually good with formulas - but I'm trying to finalize something for work and my brain is not getting me there....

I need a formula to color cell G75 Orange if cell G75 is empty AND cell F75 is not.  If cell G75 is not empty - normal formatting should apply.

Answer (score 1):

Since your post indicates only a single cell that would need such formatting, I'll address it as an accurate representation of your actual need.

Apply a "Custom formula is..." CF rule to G75:

`=AND(G75="",F75<>"")`